# Python Error: OrderedDict Object Has No Attribute OrderedDict Root

Tags: python, class, ordereddictionary

As a new python programmer, I'm practicing the LRU Cache Problem from Leetcode
Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/

Problem Description:

Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and put.

get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.
put(key, value) - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the least recently used item before inserting a new item.

Here is the solution provided by Leetcode:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
class LRUCache(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        """
        :type capacity: int
        """
        self.capacity = capacity

    def get(self, key):
        """
        :type key: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if key not in self:
            return - 1

        self.move_to_end(key)
        return self[key]

    def put(self, key, value):
        """
        :type key: int
        :type value: int
        :rtype: void
        """
        if key in self:
            self.move_to_end(key)
        self[key] = value
        if len(self) > self.capacity:
            self.popitem(last = False)
```

However I came across the following error when submitting the code:

Line 29: AttributeError: 'LRUCache' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'

Could anyone give me some hints why I got that error? Really appreciate it?

Comment: Is that line 29 in your code? Which lines is that?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

you should choose python3 as compile language.
[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) has some new property in python3

Comment: It'd be nice if you presented some of these *new properties*.